# PuTTY only executing the first command in a script specified by -m

Tags: command-line, backup, putty

I try to do a automatic backup of our Avocent Console server.

Content of `backup.cmd`:

```
putty.exe -ssh root@acs01.NULL.local -pw secretpw -m acs01.txt
```

Content of `acs01.txt`:

```
cli
cd system_tools/
save_configuration
set ip_address=10.0.0.1
set path_and_filename=/avocent/acs01
set username=ftpacs01
set password=anothersecretpw
save
finish
exit
exit
```

All works fine, but I have one problem. PuTTY comes only to execute the command `cli`, all other commands are not executed.

Is it possible to do a short break after each command?

Or is it because the `cli` is a separate interface in the Avocent?

Thank you

Comment: What kind of system is this. What is the cli command.
If this is bash, you should not need to put delays in between the commands.

Comment: What system is the SSH server on? I'm presuming Windows. If so, what's the CLI command directed at?

Comment: If you're saying that the `cli` command starts its own pseudo-shell, then yes, this is the problem.  The real shell is likely waiting for the `cli` processes to complete before continuing with the other commands.  If you were to exit the `cli` application it would probably run the other commands.

Comment: @heavyd any idea what his cli program is?

Comment: Looks like an [Avocent Command Line Configuration Utility](http://community.emerson.com/networkpower/support/avocent/serial/acs6000/w/wiki/1054.acs6000-quick-guide-using-cli-to-setup-a-serial-port)

Comment: @heavyd When you say a pseudo-shell, is that just a program that reads from stdin?

Comment: @barlop, really I just mean an application that acts like a shell, giving you a command prompt, and accepting a limited set of commands, but its probably not as full featured as a shell like bash.

Comment: @heavyd  I have heard that ssh -T can make a difference between pseudo terminal allocation or not..(-t is forced pseudo terminal, -T is no pseudo terminal)  Though when I do ssh -T 127.0.0.1 I get prompted for a password and also without it.. Are you aware of pseudo terminal being toggled in relation to ssh ? (in terms of.. then showing further what is meant by the term)?

Comment: @barlop, Yeah, I'm aware of of the `-T` flag and allocating pseudo-TTYs.  That is not what I'm talking about, I'm talking about an application that acts like a shell (shell and TTY are different), but is not a real shell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27402/discussion-between-barlop-and-heavyd).

Comment: Your should tag your question with appropriate system tag to get more attention from experts on the system.

Answer (score 1):

If the `cli` starts a "new shell", the master shell waits for it to exit and never runs your other commands.

Though, you apparently want to run your commands within the `cli` shell, not after it (maybe except the second `exit`, which probably should exit the master shell).

For that you have to use an appropriate syntax of your system or an appropriate command-line parameter of `cli`. You server seems to be some proprietary system, so I do not know the correct syntax. Neither I've found any appropriate command-line parameter of `cli` in documentation I've found on-line.

On Linux system a generic solution would be:

```
cli <<EOF
cd system_tools/
save_configuration
set ip_address=10.0.0.1
set path_and_filename=/avocent/acs01
set username=ftpacs01
set password=anothersecretpw
save
finish
exit
EOF
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all for reply & help.
After all, i found a solution. The avocent console server contains 2 alternative commands. Wich do exactly what i need.

`saveconf --help
restoreconf --help`

<

thx + best regards
schtebo